# Are there any decent video editors for the RasPi 3?

Tags: video, youtube

I've been making YT videos about the Raspberry Pi but have had no way to edit them on the pi. Are there any nice Raspberry Pi-compatible video editing apps?

Comment: are you using the RPi to make the videos?

Comment: to be honest, using a raspberry pi, even a 3+, to edit videos would be like driving a model T ford in an F1 race

Comment: I am using a RaspberryPi 2 rn, I have 3 and 3B+ to, I am making YouTube video on basics of the Pi, but I cannot edit them, I found some "editors" openshot and kdenlive but they both have a lot of suck fests.

Answer (score 1):

Just run `apt search video editor` and then `apt install <PackageName>` for a package you like. However all of those weren't built for raspberrypi, so they'll lag and not fully functional. I've actually written a simple [one](https://github.com/Bondpe/vira) that doesn't lag as much, but it isn't descent as well... RPI is just too weak to handle a good one.

Answer (score 0):

**Open shot video editor**

It is a very good video editor, but I recommend editing 480p videos.

https://www.openshot.org/

Answer (score 0):

id recommend using an online one like kapwing.
it's the one i use....

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try Kdenlive, but running on anything worse than a Pi4 with 4gb of RAM will be incredibly slow. If your looking to do more complicated video editing you need to use a different, more powerful computer as the Raspberry Pi just doesn't have the capability for that sort of thing.

https://kdenlive.org